# Pandas - Calculate daily percentage

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

i have the following issue:

```
2018-03-07 18:00:00    NW
2018-03-07 19:00:00    NW
2018-03-07 20:00:00    NW
2018-03-07 21:00:00     W
2018-03-07 22:00:00     W
2018-03-07 23:00:00     W
2018-03-08 00:00:00     W
2018-03-08 01:00:00    NW
2018-03-08 02:00:00    NW
2018-03-08 03:00:00    NW
2018-03-08 04:00:00    NW
2018-03-08 05:00:00    SW
2018-03-08 06:00:00    SE
2018-03-08 07:00:00    NE
2018-03-08 08:00:00     E
2018-03-08 09:00:00     W
2018-03-08 10:00:00     W
2018-03-08 11:00:00    NW
```

A Dataframe (dfWdir) which includes a hourly timestamp for a total of 360 days and the average wind direction in this hour as a label. Eg: N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW.
I now want to know how much precent of the day there is wind blowing in north direction or any ohter direction. So at the end every precentige of a day would add up to 100%. EG: We have day 2018-03-07 and 20% of the wind is coming from NW direction 10% of S direction and so on.

By the following Code i get to the solution:

```
df2 = df.resample('D')['Wind'].value_counts()
df2.name = 'count_Wind'
df2 = df2.reset_index('Wind')

df3 = df2.resample('D')['count_Wind'].sum()
df2['percent'] = df2['count_Wind'].div(df3) * 100
```

[image: final Dataframe]

But the result shall be shown in a plot.area() graphic. So I need a column for each possible Winddirection for each timestep. Within this columns are the precent for each timestep.

i am thankful for any help!

Comment: Added a follow up question

Comment: I saw that you changed your question. I suggest to return the original question and make a new post on how to make a graph, and if my answer helped you, please mark it as useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Date` as index, [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by day and count `Wind` unique value

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date' : [
        '2018-03-07 18:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 19:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 20:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 21:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 22:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 23:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 00:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 01:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 02:00:00'
    ],
    'Wind' : ['NW','NW','NW','W','W','W','W','NW','NW']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')

df2 = df.resample('D')['Wind'].value_counts()
df2.name = 'count_Wind'
df2 = df2.reset_index('Wind')

df3 = df2.resample('D')['count_Wind'].sum()
df2['percent'] = df2['count_Wind'].div(df3) * 100
```

the result:

```
df2.head()


            Wind    count_Wind  percent
Date            
2018-03-07  NW  3   50.000000
2018-03-07  W   3   50.000000
2018-03-08  NW  2   66.666667
2018-03-08  W   1   33.333333
```

If you don't need `count_Wind`, use `del df2['count_Wind']`

Answer (score 0):

Create two groupby objects. One counts the wind by the day, and the second counts total wind count by day. Then you can us the div method at the day level to get your answer.

```
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Date' : [
        '2018-03-07 18:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 19:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 20:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 21:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 22:00:00',
        '2018-03-07 23:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 00:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 01:00:00',
        '2018-03-08 02:00:00'
    ],
    'Wind' : ['NW','NW','NW','W','W','W','W','NW','NW']} )

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',)

    Date              Wind
0   2018-03-07 18:00:00 NW
1   2018-03-07 19:00:00 NW
2   2018-03-07 20:00:00 NW
3   2018-03-07 21:00:00 W
4   2018-03-07 22:00:00 W
5   2018-03-07 23:00:00 W
6   2018-03-08 00:00:00 W
7   2018-03-08 01:00:00 NW
8   2018-03-08 02:00:00 NW 

# split datetime into day and time

df['Day'] = [d.date() for d in df['Date']]
df['Time'] = [d.time() for d in df['Date']]


# groupby Day and Wind,, then group on day, then divide 

day_wind = df.groupby(['Day', 'Wind']).agg({'Time': 'count'})
day_total = df.groupby(['Day']).agg({'Time': 'count'})
day_wind.div(day_total, level='Day').round(3) * 100

Output: 
               Time
Day        Wind 
2018-03-07  NW  50.0
             W  50.0
2018-03-08  NW  66.7
             W  33.3
```

Comment: i dont understand it. My series is: index(timestamp) and Wind.

Comment: You basic information changed, I clipboraded he first example. See revised to meet your current data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your result should exactly look like and assume that the colums of the DataFrame are `Date` and `Direction`.

You get the absolute values for the wind direction for every day by:

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.floor('D'), 'Direction'])['Direction'].agg(len).unstack().fillna(0)
```

The number of hours per day in your dataset:

```
df.groupby([df.Date.dt.floor('D')])['Date'].agg(len)
```

Combining this leads to the relative values.